# ImagePullBackOff error in Kubernetes (in AKS) while pulling image from ACR and all pods are Evicted

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, kubernetes, azure-container-registry

I have an image of size ~ 6GB, which is successfully built by Jenkins and pushed to ACR. When Kubernetes tries to pull the same, I get the ImagePullBackOff error. The same pull is tried for 3 times automatically, but during the third time, other pods were evicted with a message "**DiskPressure True**", "**kubelet has disk pressure**". Node has sufficient disk, sufficient memory, but I am not sure why DiskPressure is True. I don't have much experience in CI, would someone help in fixing this issue?

The configuration is as follows,

- AKS Cluster
- Kubernetes Version: 1.11.4
- Cluster has 2 nodes with 4 Core Processor, 16GB RAM, and each node has 30GB Disk space.

Please let me know if further details are required.

Comment: i think it has a specific percentage of disk size allocated, try increasing disk size

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thanks for replying. Could you please guide me on how to increase the disk space.

Comment: just expand disk dise in azure and then in the vm

Comment: Thank you. Increasing the disk space to 50GB on each node helped me to fix the issue, but if the issue persists after a few more new builds, is this a feasible solution? Is there any other solution to overcome this issue?

Comment: i'm pretty sure those settings are not changeable as they are kubelet settings (aks doesnt allow to manage those). you can configure node disk space when you create them to be anysize, virtually. normally you would alter kubelet settings https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case the error was due to insufficient space on the nodes. increasing the space on the disk fixed this error.